# How to grout in order to minimize uneven tile spacing?

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile, grout

I have tiled my shower wall with hexagonal tiles & subway tiles.

I am about to grout both walls BUT because the hexagonal tiles don't space out evenly, I am afraid white grout would show the uneven spacing imperfections too much.

Would it look weird with the subway tiles with white grout ?

What color grout should I use for the dark tiles to minimize uneven spacing ?

[image]

Comment: aren’t they hexagonal?

Comment: Decorating advice is off-topic here, but obviously a dark or matching grout will be less conspicuous.

Comment: Not really decorating advice. OP is asking how to minimize uneven spacing.

Answer (score 3):

This is really going to be opinion based but I would be looking for a dark blue, tile matching grout. The white grout is going to tie all those shooting rays  of white together and will lose the effect. The imperfections would be minor unless your mother-in-law or father-in-law wanted to make a point in which case no color grout would hide it. Just my humble opinion. You could even think about using the same color for the subway tile depending on your color coordination. Caution: no one has ever let me decorate their house.

Comment: LOL!!! Thank you for your opinion. I think I will use a similar dark grout. Not sure about bluish grout for the white tiles, that might look a little Halloween :)

Answer (score 0):

I think a dark blue, close to the hexagonal tile would look best for both tiles. The closer the match to the hex, the more the grout lines blend in, and extending the color into the subway tiles carries the theme.